# How to know if I can update my toyota corolla 2018 LE car with entune causing confusion

Tags: toyota, corolla

I have a toyota corolla 2018 LE (no navigation) Canada/Ontario

Model ID 15TBDANA-CA01

Hard No 86140-02520

All systems is UU.11.17

According to this https://www.toyota.com/firmware-updates/download that model number indicates its just entune audio and not entune audio plus.

I'm trying to update my car with whatever is available if appropriate.

If I go to here

https://www.toyota.ca/toyota/en/my-toyota/multimedia-system-update

and put in my model as Corolla/2018 and face plate number 100639, it shows me an update for UU.11.34. However when reading the instructions for faceplate number, I am seeing:

- IMPORTANT: If your Toyota vehicle is equipped with Entune, please refer to the instructions for checking the Entune part number. Vehicles equipped with Entune are not provided with Face Plate Numbers.

The entune part number I got from reading the instructions is just the Hard No list above.

What confuses me is that it says cars equipped with the Entune don't have face plate numbers, but I can clearly see that my car has a face plate number, and that according to the first link, it indicates I have regular entune audio. So I am not sure if this update is appropriate for me, or is there something else I need.

Does anyone know?